# Storing Data across Columns vs Storing data in a JSON Column in MYSQL

Tags: sql, mysql, rdbms

Lets say I have a table **T1**. Initially it has **ID, Identifier, C1, C2** as columns. As time goes by I will be adding new columns **C3, C4 and so on**. Will it be better to have the columns as **ID, Identifier, Info** with **Info** being a JSON column with **C1, C2, C3 as keys** and their corresponding values. What will be the read, write, update performance considering a scale of around 10^9 records.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use a relational database then you should use a relational model. While many RDBMSs can now handle JSON that doesn't mean you should hold your data as JSON (by default).

A good example of when to use JSON is if your source data is supplied as JSON. You can load it as-is into your RDBMS and then use SQL to "unpack" it from the staging table JSON into a proper relational format.

Regarding performance, there are so many variables involved it is impossible to provide a useful answer. The only way for you to get a useful answer is for you to test it on your environment with your data and with queries relevant to you

Comment: @AlgorithmicDUMB - Implementing and testing, of course, means twice the work.  But it is a good exercise.  It could even lead to you providing your on Answer.@algorithmicDUMB -

Answer (score 0):

- If you need to include the 'columns' in `WHERE` or `ORDER BY` clauses, make them actual columns.
- If you have a bunch of miscellany, especially if the values are often optional, then use JSON.
- Adding a second table (vertically partitioning) when you add more columns; then `LEFT JOINing` to get C3 (etc) -- There are pros and cons to this 'solution'.
- [*Entity-Attribute-Value*](https://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/eav) schemas are notoriously problematic.
- MySQL 8.0 can `ALTER TABLE .. ADD COLUMN ..` "instantly".  But there are caveats.

If you try to do Where/Order on JSON fields for a billion rows, your computer will melt down into a slag heap.

If you want more advice on C1/C2/C3, please explain what your application is, how often columns will be added, how likely the cells will be NULL (missing, omitted, etc).  We can discuss the alternatives.